# java open a frame from another class

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

So I am trying to just make it so when I click a button it will open a frame from another class my filechooser frame just won't open.

This is the class called mainFrame:

```
package javatut;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class mainFrame {

    private JFrame frmMainwindow;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mainFrame window = new mainFrame();
                    window.frmMainwindow.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public mainFrame() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmMainwindow = new JFrame();
        frmMainwindow.setTitle("Mainwindow");
        frmMainwindow.setBounds(100, 100, 280, 150);
        frmMainwindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmMainwindow.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse");
        btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                myButtonAction();
            }
        });
        btnBrowse.setBounds(155, 11, 100, 23);
        frmMainwindow.getContentPane().add(btnBrowse);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(10, 12, 135, 20);
        frmMainwindow.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
    }

    private void myButtonAction(){
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }
}
```

And this is the FileChooser class called simply frame:

```
package javatut;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class frame {


    private JFrame frmFilechooser;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame window = new frame();
                    window.frmFilechooser.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public frame() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmFilechooser = new JFrame();
        frmFilechooser.setTitle("FileChooser");
        frmFilechooser.setBounds(100, 100, 470, 350);
        frmFilechooser.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmFilechooser.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        frmFilechooser.getContentPane().add(fileChooser);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most logical solution is to change the `myButtonAction()` method to:

```
private void myButtonAction() {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frmMainwindow);
    if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        // do something with the chosen file ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this worked thanks. I kept trying to find stuff on this but couldn't find it. could you by change explain line by line why and how it worked? sorry if is much to ask but I want to learn not just copy

Comment: *"..I want to learn.."* Start by learning where the Java Docs are, and reading the description of each method used. For example, [`JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showOpenDialog-java.awt.Component-). But more generally .. X+Java+Tutorial in your favorite search engine, where 'X' is the class of interest, in this case, `JFileChooser` .. The tutorial explains things we don't have time or space to, and usually includes complete working examples.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're just missing two lines.  The first in mainFrame's myButtonAction:

```
 private void myButtonAction(){
  //  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    new frame();
}
```

And the other in frame's initialize:

```
    private void initialize() {
    frmFilechooser = new JFrame();
    frmFilechooser.setTitle("FileChooser");
    frmFilechooser.setBounds(100, 100, 470, 350);
    frmFilechooser.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmFilechooser.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    frmFilechooser.getContentPane().add(fileChooser);
    frmFilechooser.setVisible(true);
}
```

(I just added the setVisible line at the bottom)

Comment: `frmFilechooser.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` Try closing the frame based file chooser..